# Arabic characters as input in windows phone 8 application

Tags: input, textbox, windows-phone-8, arabic

I'm developing one **windows phone 8 application which should work in both English and Arabic languages.**

User can change the language from English to Arabic from application's Settings Page.

When user changes the language from English to Arabic, I'm changing the application's culture to the selected language.

```
if (Constants.selectedLanguage.Equals("English"))
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
        }
        else
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar");
        }
```

Now the content is displaying in the selected language.

But when user clicks on the text box, the keyboard is coming with English letters only, even though the culture is set to Arabic.

**So how should I give the input in Arabic characters, when the application's culture is set to Arabic.**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can change the language of the keyboard while its open by taping in the button on which en is written ....

According to me you cannot set any default langauge of the keyboard as it is changed by the language of your phoe not your app...

Comment: I didn't find the **en** on the keyboard

Comment: @SureshBasina you need to add the english keyboard in the phone settings.

Comment: I'm working with emulator. Then how can i add arabic keeyboard to the emulator.

Comment: In windows phone 8 emulator ,we have an option to change keypad language.Follow setting=>keypad=>add keypads=>select your language.Now your keypad will be automatically showing your selected languages on "Eng" button.